# How to perform batch inserts to clickhouse using JDBC client?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I am trying to write into clickhouse DB using Clickhouse JDBC client (0.4.0)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.clickhouse/clickhouse-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
    <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[I am following this example to do batch insert](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/33245#issuecomment-1003579177)

Basically,

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "insert into mytable select col1, col2 from input('col1 String, col2 DateTime64(3), col3 Int32')")) {
    // the column definition will be parsed so the driver knows there are 3 parameters: col1, col2 and col3
    ps.setString(1, "test"); // col1
    ps.setObject(2, LocalDateTime.now()); // col2, setTimestamp is slow and not recommended
    ps.setInt(3, 123); // col3
    ps.addBatch(); // parameters will be write into stream in binary format
    ...
    ps.executeBatch(); // stream everything on-hand into ClickHouse
}
```

I am adding 10000 rows to the batch before executing `ps.executeBatch()`.
Is it the right and correct way to do batch inserts to clickhouse ?

Is it similar as doing ?
`insert into mytable values(...)(...)...(...)`

Just wanted to make sure that I am doing the batch inserts the right way.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. From that GitHub comment example: `insert into mytable select col1, col2 from input('col1 String, col2 DateTime64(3), col3 Int32')` (#1) is not similar to `insert into mytable values(...)(...)...(...)` (#3) cause #3 will generate huge SQL statement while #1 won't.

Comment: A more correct approach would be to use `JdbcTemplate`, and use the `batchUpdate` method.